# How to use Icon Only button in Nav Bar (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use some icon only buttons in the footer Nav Bar but no success. I have tried the following;

```
<!--Footer-->
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="flat-mail" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="flat-camera" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="flat-heart" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="flat-eye" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

**Also...**

```
<!--Footer-->
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-icon-notext" data-icon="flat-mail" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-icon-notext" data-icon="flat-camera" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-icon-notext" data-icon="flat-heart" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-icon-notext" data-icon="flat-eye" data-role="button">Yes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Please, can someone put me through

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (remove the Yes word):

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 <div data-role="navbar" >
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-icon="camera" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-icon="heart" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fZN9A/1/)**

This is the reference icons for jquery mobile:
**[JQuery Mobile Icons](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_ref_icons.asp)**

Comment: My icons show fine, i just want only the icons to show without text